# Remote logging and /var/log/messages on 11.10 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, logging

There is no direct connection between those two but I will try to explain.

1. As far as I understood `/var/log/messages` is eliminated from latest Ubuntu disto and now all goes to `/var/log/syslog`. Fine, I didn't have `/var/log/messages`.
2. I needed to have remote syslog facility, so googling brought me to installing `sysklogd`. After installing it, remote syslog worked well, but then `/var/log/messages` appeared.

Now the question is - how to solve this nicely? Was it mistake to install sysklogd and there was some better way? Should I now modify sysklogd configuration (or some other configs) in order to eliminate `/var/log/messages` again?

Comment: why do you need to eliminate messages? It/s the same, as long as you know where to look for the actual messages. If you are collecting logs on a remote syslog server then the local files are just in case if the remote server would not be available.

Comment: Because I want to keep the system as it was designed, according to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/51265/where-is-var-log-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, what really matters is 1) are the things you want logged being logged and 2) can you find them.  If you're doing remote syslog logging to somewhere you're actually gonig to pay attention to, you could even turn off local logging; it depends on the situation and  your preferences.  There's nothing magical about /var/log/messages; it's just a file that 'usually' exists, like /etc/inittab, for instance - it's traditional, but traditions change.